A disabled server-wide Azure SQL user is still able to log in
I want to block access for a specific SQL login entirely, but the server continues to accept their credentials when their database is specified in the connection properties:

Those were the scripts used:
-- Master

CREATE LOGIN pmp
    WITH PASSWORD = 'xxx'
GO

-- User database

CREATE USER pmp
    FOR LOGIN pmp
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'pmp'
GO

-- Master

ALTER LOGIN pmp DISABLE
GO

Object Explorer


Are there databases where there is a USER created for user authentication, rather than login authentication?

@ThomA Yes, there is a user with his default database. I used the command 'CREATE USER pmp FOR LOGIN pmp' when I granted access to him.

Make sure you didn't create the user with a password, making it a contained database user, instead of for a login.

Then the LOGIN would be unable to authenticate, @SergioJr . There's something you're telling us that's incorrect. Perhaps the LOGIN you disabled and you one amyoure authenticating as aren't the same. Perhaps it really is using USER authentication. Perhaps you're connecting to a different server...

@ThomA I complemented the question with the way I used to create the login and user

The server takes some time to propagate the change to the user.
All it took was waiting approximately 5 minutes for the user to start receiving a connection refusal, displaying the message that their credentials had been deactivated.
My mistake was to perform the tests immediately after the change.

That situation only happens when you create a Server Login and then creates a Contained Database User, but the database user is not connected to the login in the master. Contained database user does not depend on the logins at the server level. You need to create the user with the "FOR LOGIN" clause that is what connect the user at the database level to the login at the server level.
The correct syntax for creating a server login that is used on the databases created on that server is the following:
-- On master database
CREATE LOGIN TestUser
    WITH PASSWORD = 'ThisIsAStrongPassword!' 
GO

CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO

-- create user on database level

CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO


I dropped all users/logins created before and ran the updated script mentioned on the question, but the user is still able to log in and access the data

Did you test with the TestUser on my script? Disable (or delete) the login at the server level and the user at the user at the database level should not be able to connect to the database or server.

I found the difference; the user is specifying his database in the connection properties. How can I block all databases?

Contained database users cannot be blocked at the server level.  I you create database users connected to their login in the master, once you disable or delete the login on the master the user won't be able to connect. You can also remove all contained database users that are associated with a person.

The user IS associated with a server login through the FOR LOGIN argument when creating the database user. But disabling the server login is taking effect only when I leave the "default" database on connection properties.

Please consider to use the revoke connect as a way to disbale the user at the database level. REVOKE CONNECT FROM [username];
